# Visual Studio - Cannot remove specific ".lib" file from Linker's Command Line. How can I edit it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, linker-errors, lib

[screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egZ6G.png)

I attempted to set up the Linker to direct to my ".lib" files(In the process of setting up Visual Studio to work with DirectX 9 as a cpp win32 project).

I made these changes in 
`Project->Properties->Linker->Input` (also in General)  by adding **d3d9.lib** and **d3dx9.lib** to the Additional Directories box.  (See Photo Below)

I must have missed a semi-colon separating the **kernel32.lib** and **d3dx9.lib** the first time, because now under the Linker's Command Line (AS SEEN IN THE PHOTO) it lists **"d3dx9.libkernel32.lib"** as a single lib file to search for in there.
I cannot edit this read-only Command Line.  I cannot run my project because I get LNK1104 Errors saying:

> fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3dx9.libkernel32.lib'.

No matter what I do to edit and change the 'Input' and 'General' categories of Linker dependencies, I can't remove the phony file from the Linker Command Line.  I even uninstalled VS, cleaned VS registries, and reinstalled Visual Studio a couple of times and STILL have that missing Linker error there, with the phony file still showing in the Command Line. Creating new projects and resetting VS to default settings hasn't helped either...   :(
     Please Help,
Thanks

Comment: I think the linker references are stored in the project properties file, so reinstalling VS didn't work.  Can you open the `.vcxproj` file with your favourite text editor, and delete the offending linker reference?

Comment: @Bernard In the **.vcxproj** I did see some things related to the Linker settings that VS allows me to change inside properties anyway, but I didn't see the actual linker references in there.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Project->Properties->Linker->Input, and see if you find the offending linker reference in the "Additional Dependencies" field.

[image: Steps 1 and 2]

2. If not, click the arrow on the right side and click "Edit..." in the drop-down menu.
3. In the window that appears, click "Macros>>".

[image: Step 3]

4. Edit the "%(AdditionalDependencies)% field to get rid of the offending linker reference.

[image: Step 4]

Comment: This doesn't work.  Once I'm in the window of your last screenshot in **Macros**, it won't let me change / edit anything.  Thanks for the input anyways.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
After many hours of trying to solve this myself and having a bunch of my peers give her a go, I introduced the problem to my Professor, who didn't exactly seem to know what he was doing either, but he managed to get rid of the offending Linker reference after poking around in the **Properties** window and the **Linker dependencies** window that **@Bernard** mentioned.
It seemed kind of lucky having previously changed all of those settings multiple times to no success... I'm not exactly sure the order of which we changed the properties but it had something to do with the order that we **unchecked** all those ***Inherit from parent or project defaults*** check boxes (one of them is seen in @Bernard 's 2nd last screenshot) and resaving the **.lib** files in the **Linker's** ***Additional Dependencies***.
Needless to say, now it somehow works!

Thanks everyone for your help.
Cheers!